# Repeating column names when outputting a query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to repeat the names of a database table's columns when executing a query whenever the GROUP BY info change?  My query is group by a column.

```
SELECT  name.fname as First_Name,  
  name.sales as Sales, 
  name.city as City 
FROM name 
GROUP BY city 
ORDER BY name.fname;
```

Comment: your query doesn't make sense: You are not actually grouping by anything (you have no aggregate columns). What order do you want?

Comment: can you show an example of the results you are looking for?

Comment: When you group by a column, you only get one row for each value of that column -- that's what "group by" means in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT  name.fname as First_Name,  
  name.sales as Sales, 
  name.city as City 
FROM name 
ORDER BY city, fname;
```